# When using Remix Ethereum get Error types/value length mismatch (previously run was ok.)

Tags: solidity, remix, openzeppelin

creation of meatFarm errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":2,"values":4}, value={"types":["address","address"],"values":["0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138","0xd8b934580fcE35a11B58C6D73aDeE468a2833fa8","",""]}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)

i encounter above error which require 4 values but types is only 2. wondering what have I missing.
[image]

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract meatFarm {

    mapping(address => uint256[]) public stakingBalance;
    mapping(address => bool) public isStaking;
    mapping(address => uint256) public startTime;
    mapping(address => uint256) public meatBalance;

    string public name = "MeatFarm";

    IERC721 public cdnoToken;
    IERC20 public meatToken;

    event Stake(address indexed from, uint256 indexed);
    event Unstake(address indexed from, uint256 indexed);
    event YieldWithdraw(address indexed to, uint256 amount);

    constructor(
        IERC721 _cdnoToken,
        IERC20 _meatToken
        ) {
            cdnoToken = _cdnoToken;
            meatToken = _meatToken;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that you are passing two empty arguments.
I'm able to deploy it in Remix, using your code, with arguments:

```
"0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138","0xd8b934580fcE35a11B58C6D73aDeE468a2833fa8"
```

Comment: If using truffle it works fine but when I use remix I get above errors which I does not make sense

Comment: Is that a new version of REMIX bug>?  which version you are using?
previously it works fine but after the update to 12 -> 12.1 12.2 bugged

Answer (score 0):

Not code probelm is remix version updated bugged!